# Honeycomb and cursors

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have this activity that was completely converted to use honeycomb. I reworked all the cursor management to use the new cursorLoader. Everything works great on all other os versions (using the compatibility library), but still does not work on honeycomb. The following stack trace is extremely difficult to understand because it does not tell me which cursor or which line is failing. Furthermore, when debugging, no line of code in ParentActivity is ever executed. This error is happening when I resume the ParentActivity. Works great when I start the activity but fails when returning to it.

```
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.ParentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1028)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4394)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4420)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
05-29 17:23:32.978: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31692):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the effect of some changes that were made in Honeycomb to how Cursors are managed. Previously if you called `startManagingCursor` more than once everything continued to work normally, now it will causes an `IllegalStateException` because the activity is trying to requery a closed cursor. The solution is to close the old cursor before calling `startManagingCursor` again (Like when swapping cursors).

So your `ParentActivity` is doing this indirectly as a result of the managed cursor lifecycle inside an `Activity`.

Now you mentioned your were using the ACL and CursorLoader, make sure you are calling [swapCursor(Cursor c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) when changing cursors and this should fix your issues.

You can see some of the discussion of this here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/658133bec901d7e

Comment: I was somewhat confused by your response since I'm not really swapping any cursors but what I did find was that I was still using startManagingCursor and I removed those lines and all is happy now. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond and pointing me in the right direction. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: @Michael Little no problem, I just wanted to cover all my bases because they're are a few ways to arrive at the same problem. Glad I could help

Comment: Better get rid of startManagingCursor, create mCursor in your activity. Close it in onPause or onDestroy (depending on if you populate it in onResume or onCreate).

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem.  Here is what I have done.  In all the activities that I've called startManagingCursor, I override it as:

```
@Override
public void startManagingCursor(Cursor c) {

    // To solve the following error for honeycomb:
    // java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VersionUtil.HONEYCOMB) {
        super.startManagingCursor(c);
    }
}
```

This makes my app run correctly on Honeycomb and earlier versions.

Comment: Removing startManagingCursor also fixed the issue for me. When using a managedQuery, I had to call stopManagingCursor in honeycomb.

Comment: Hey, maybe a silly question, but what is `VersionUtil`? I'm not able to import it.

Comment: It's my internal class specifying the honeycomb version 
`public class VersionUtil {
...
public static final int HONEYCOMB = 11;
...
}`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problems and think I might have found the problem and a "clean" fix. (I think stopping to manage the cursors at all is not a good idea)

I use Adapter.changeCursor in some activities which worked great in all versions except for honeycomb. The changeCursor method closes the old cursor, but obviously don't stop managing that cursor. So the activity keeps managing that old cursor which is already closed. In a restart of the activity it does try to requery it, without checking if it is closed.

So my solution is:

```
Cursor oldCursor = mAdapter.getCursor();
mAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
stopManagingCursor(oldCursor);
```

Until now I can't reproduce the Exception again.

Comment: Where do you do this, in onPause? Maybe your problem is different than mine. I never change the cursor in the first place, but I still get the error.

Comment: I do it at the place where (ever) I changed the cursor. Maybe your problem is different than mine.